# encoding special characters in javascript/python

Tags: javascript, python, mongodb, special-characters

I'm having a lot of problems with properly processing certain special characters in my application.

Here's what I'm doing at the moment:

1. User enters a location, data is retrieved via the Google Geolocation API (full name, lat and lon) and is sent via ajax (as a JSON string) to a python script
2. The python script parses the JSON string, reads the parameters and executes a http request to an API, which runs on nodejs
3. Data is inserted into MongoDB

The problem is when there's a special character in the location name. The original location name I'm testing on has the character è. When the json is parsed in Python I get a \xc9 and after the process completes I always end up with a completely different (mostly invalid) character in the database than what was originally entered. I've tried all sorts of encoding and decoding (mostly from similar questions on stackoverflow), but I don't properly understand what exactly I should do.

Any tips would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `var myEncodedString = encodeURIComponent('your string or whatever');` in your js code